# Is there a way to change the hx-trigger on a child element

Tags: htmx

I have a form that I want to submit on change so set the hx-trigger to 'change'. However, I have some inputs in the form that I want to submit on a custom trigger because they are custom widgets and they trigger an on change before they really are changed.

This but it does not work because the on change from the form triggers anyway

```html
<form hx-trigger='change' hx-get='/example'>
  {% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
  {% if custom_widget %}
    <div hx-trigger='custom-event'>
      {{field}}
    </div
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing around and doing some more research I found that what I originally assumed was not true.

First of all `hx-trigger` is not inherited. The reason I can't modify the trigger on a child is because of how JavaScript events work. Since there is an onchange on the form it will submit anyway, even if the input has a separate event handler.

Therefore, to do this `from` is needed in the trigger to scope the event handlers to the inputs. Something along the lines of this.

```html
<form id='myForm' hx-trigger='change from:(#myForm .regular), customEvent' hx-get='/example'>
  {% for field in form %}
   
  {% if custom_widget %}
    <div class='custom'>
      {{field}}
    </div
  {% else %}
    <div class='regualar'>
      {{field}}
    </div
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

see https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/#notes

> - hx-trigger is not inherited
> - hx-trigger can be used without an AJAX request, in which case it will only fire the htmx:trigger event
> - In order to pass a CSS selector that contains whitespace (e.g. form input) to the from- or target-modifier, surround the selector in parentheses or curly brackets (e.g. from:(form input) or from:nearest (form input))

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because of [attribute inheritance](https://htmx.org/docs/#inheritance), you need to [disinherit](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-disinherit/) the form's `hx` attributes on your custom_widget div wrapper.

```
<form hx-trigger='change' hx-get='/example'>
  {% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
  {% if custom_widget %}
    <div hx-trigger='custom-event' hx-disinherit="hx-trigger">
      {{field}}
    </div
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

This will only disinherit the change attribute, if you want to disinherit all of parent's attributes, you can use `hx-disinherit="*"`.

Comment: Thought that too. Turns out `hx-trigger` is not inherited